# Java how to "tag" string through function calls

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my logic. Here's the setup.

```
input (span objects) ---> pre-processing (my function) 
---> generic spanToHtml converter --> final html
```

My pre-processing function essentially looks for my custom spans, convert them into html and insert them into the original span so the `spanToHtml` converter will work as usual. Then the final html code will have the html code I generated from my pre-processing function.

However, there is one problem. Like any good web code, `spanToHtml` sanitizes the input and escapes it. Therefore, any html tags I added in my pre-processing function gets escaped and rendered incorrectly.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I temporarily have a hacky solution where instead of using html tags, my pre-processing function will insert arbitrary "tag" strings. Then after I call `spanToHtml`, I do a post-processing replacing all those tags with actual html tags. However, that's a terrible solution.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Which pieces of code are yours and which are not? Maybe it would be easier to use some more sensible structure than strings? How does input look like? How data look like on each step?

Comment: I find this question to be vague and confusing... Where does the span to HTML converter come from? If you're dealing with a reasonable framework, there should be some option to disable the sanitization. What technologies are you using?

Comment: It's hard to tell just what your problem is, but my impression is that `spanToHtml` expects unstructured text as input, and you're trying to give it input that's structured (with HTML tags).  So you're using a function for a purpose other than the one it's designed for, generally a bad idea.  Can `spanToHtml` be called multiple times on smaller substrings, and the results concatenated together with the new tags?